# Redirect pipe contains quotation marks to a variable in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, grep, pipe

I am trying to get the number of substrings "id" in a file and save to a file
I am trying to do it this way:

`for /F %N in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -o "id" %TEMP%\jiraoutput.txt ^| "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -c "id"') do set "NUM=%N"`

But I get:

`"C:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: for starters, either temporarily put grep in your path before making the call or use progra~2 instead of Program Files so you don't need to quote.  Are you sure you need "Id" (quoted)?

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks!
Of course, I would like to understand how to use a construction similar to the one above, with quotes, so that you can, for example, use directories with spaces
But there is a solution and it's already good